# Boxplot with ggplot2 in R - returns by month

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I have computed monthly returns from a price series. I then build a dataframe as follows:

```
    y.ret_1981    y.ret_1982    y.ret_1983   y.ret_1984   y.ret_1985
1   0.0001015229  0.0030780203 -0.0052233836  0.017128325 -0.002427308
2   0.0005678989  0.0009249838 -0.0023294622 -0.030531971  0.001831160
3  -0.0019040392 -0.0021614791  0.0022451252 -0.003345983  0.005773503
4  -0.0006015118  0.0010695681  0.0052680258  0.008592513  0.009867972
5   0.0052736054 -0.0003181347 -0.0008505673 -0.000623061 -0.012225140
6   0.0014266119 -0.0101045071 -0.0003073150 -0.016084505 -0.005883687
7  -0.0069002733 -0.0078170620  0.0070058676 -0.007870294 -0.010265335
8  -0.0041963258  0.0039905142  0.0134996961 -0.002149331 -0.007860940
9   0.0020778541 -0.0038834826  0.0052289589  0.007271409 -0.005320848
10  0.0030956487 -0.0005027686 -0.0021452210  0.002502301 -0.001890657
11 -0.0032375542  0.0063916686  0.0009331531  0.004679741  0.004338580
12  0.0014882164  0.0039578527  0.0136663415  0.000000000  0.003807668
```

... where columns are the monthly returns for the years 1981 to 1985 and the rows 1 to 12 are the months of the year.

I would like to plot a a boxplot similar to the one below:

[image: boxplot]

So what can I go? And I would like my graph to read the months of the years instead of integer 1 to 12.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, add new column `month` to your original data frame containing `month.name` (built-in constant in R) and use it as factor. It is import to set also `levels=` inside the `factor()` to ensure that months are arranged in chronological order not the alphabetical.

Then melt this data frame from wide format to long format. In `ggplot()` use `month` as x values and `value` as y.

```
df$month<-factor(month.name,levels=month.name)
library(reshape2)
df.long<-melt(df,id.vars="month")
ggplot(df.long,aes(month,value))+geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your reply. i don't understand well how you use value in ggplot(df.long,aes(month,value))+geom_boxplot() . did your rename the columns ?

Comment: Function melt() automatically puts all values in column value. You can change it using argument value.name= inside melt().

Comment: ah! my problem was i didn't use the right data argument with melt(). i used month.abb instead of month.name . thank you very much, indeed. i know almost nothing about the reshape2 package. :)